# AWK: backslash as one of the many field seperators

Tags: bash, awk

Help pls. what am I am doing wrong? How do I escape the backslash? I have tried 2,3,4 `\` to try to escape it. pls help.

```
echo "email@gmail.com:aaa/bbb\ccc ddd" |awk -F"[/@: \]" '
{
  print $1 " | " $2 " | " $3 " | " $4 " | " $5
}'
```

Expected output:

```
email | gmail.com | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to write your script:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'email@gmail.com:aaa/bbb\ccc ddd' |
awk -F'[/@: \\\\]' -v OFS=' | ' '
    {
        $1 = $1
        print
    }
'
email | gmail.com | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd
```

The difference between quotes in shell (note: this has nothing to do with awk or any other tool you might call from shell, this is all about shell):

1. `'foo'` = "hey, shell, stay the hell away from this, do NOT look at it"
2. `"foo"` = "hey, shell, please interpret this to expand variables, etc."
3. `foo`   = "hey, shell, please interpret this to do the same stuff as for double quotes but also do globbing, file name expansion, etc".

See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes for all the gory details.

So the shell quoting rule is:

**Always use single quotes** around all strings and scripts unless you **need** the shell to expand variables and then use double quotes unless you also **need** the shell to do globbing and then use no quotes.

Now for the awk part - when you specify an FS as a string you are actually writing a dynamic (aka computed) regexp (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Computed-Regexps) and as such awk has to parse that string twice, once to convert it to a regexp and then to use it as a regexp. That means that any backslash you want to be present in the regexp has to appear twice in the string so that after the first pass of converting the string to a regexp there's still 1 backslash left.

So if you want a regexp like that lets you find, say, `|` or `\` in the input then you'd like to just write:

```
$ echo 'ab\c' | awk '/[|\]/'
awk: cmd. line:1: /[|\]/
awk: cmd. line:1:  ^ unterminated regexp
awk: cmd. line:1: error: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[|\]//
```

but you can't because `\` is the escape character in a regexp so you need to escape IT to make it literal:

```
$ echo 'ab\c' | awk '/[|\\]/'
ab\c
```

Now if you wanted to use a dynamic instead of literal regexp (this applies to setting `FS` too) you'd like to do:

```
$ echo 'ab\c' | awk -v re='[|\\]' '$0 ~ re'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: invalid regexp: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[|\]/
```

but you can't because the string that represents the dynamic regexp has to be converted into a literal and that uses up one set of backslashes so you have to write:

```
$ echo 'ab\c' | awk -v re='[|\\\\]' '$0 ~ re'
ab\c
```

If you instead wrote (now about to [incorrectly] use double quotes instead of single):

```
$ echo 'ab\c' | awk -v re="[|\\\\]" '$0 ~ re'
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: invalid regexp: Unmatched [, [^, [:, [., or [=: /[|\]/
```

then you'd be asking the shell to interpret the string before awk even sees it and so you'd need yet another layer of backslashes for THAT pass to consume:

```
$ echo 'ab\c' | awk -v re="[|\\\\\\\\]" '$0 ~ re'
ab\c
```

So - just don't do that unless you **need** to invite the shell to interpret the string. Simply follow the shell quoting rules I gave above.

Now, remember - **awk is not shell**, so double quotes inside an awk script are part of the awk language, not part of the shell language, and so do not have the same semantics. When you write `"foo"` in awk you're not inviting awk or the shell or anything else to interpret it, you're writing a literal string, just like if you wrote `'foo'` in shell, so you don't need any extra escapes for a string inside an awk script:

```
$ echo 'ab\c' | awk 'BEGIN{re="[|\\\\]"} $0 ~ re'
ab\c
```

That last statement assumes your awk script is stored in a file or inside single quotes being invoked from shell. If you choose to use double quotes around the awk script instead of single then you are inviting a world of pain having to escape `$` signs, double up on backslashes, etc. as you're asking the shell to interpret the whole ask script before awk sees it so - don't do that. On Windows I understand you have to which is why the standard advice there is to save the awk script in a file instead of quoting it on the command line.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround with GNU awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]"; OFS=" | "} {$1=$1; print}'
```

Use everything but `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9`, `.` and `-` as input field separator.

Or replace `FS="[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]"` with `FPAT="[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+"` to define which characters are part of a field.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `sub` to get rid of `'\'` and simplify the field-separator, e.g.

```
awk -F"[@:/ ]" '{ sub(/\\/,"/",$0); print $1 " | " $2 " | " $3 " | " $4 " | " $5 " | " $6 }'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ printf "email@gmail.com:aaa/bbb\ccc ddd" | 
awk -F"[@:/ ]" '{ sub(/\\/,"/",$0); print $1 " | " $2 " | " $3 " | " $4 " | " $5 " | " $6 }'
email | gmail.com | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd
```

Adding the `OFS` improvement from @Cyrus, the expression simplifies to:

```
awk -F"[@:/ ]" -v OFS=" | " '{ sub(/\\/,"/",$0); $1=$1 }1'
```

(same output, but less of a picket-fence look to the command)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, you need [all the backslashes you can get](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Command-Line-Field-Separator), plus avoid shell pitfalls:

```
$ echo "email@gmail.com:aaa/bbb\ccc ddd" | awk -F"[/@:\\\\ ]" '{ print $1 " | " $2 " | " $3 " | " $4 " | " $5 " | " $6 }'
email | gmail.com | aaa | bbb\ccc | ddd | 
$ echo "email@gmail.com:aaa/bbb\ccc ddd" | awk -F'[/@:\\\\ ]' '{ print $1 " | " $2 " | " $3 " | " $4 " | " $5 " | " $6 }'
email | gmail.com | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd
```

Note that the difference between the two is the shell quoting, `""` interprets backslashes, whereas `''` doesn't.

(Also, you have 6 output items, so you need to add  `" | " $6`)

*EDIT*:

- This [isn't specific to gawk](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html).
- It's specific to `-F`, as opposed to setting `FS` directly from the script (`BEGIN { FS="[/@:\\\\ ]"}`).
- As noted in [Cyrus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952218/10678955) and [David C. Rankin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64952382/10678955), you can simplify the script using `OFS=" | "`.

So the cleanest version would be:

```
$ echo "email@gmail.com:aaa/bbb\ccc ddd" | awk 'BEGIN { FS="[/@:\\\\ ]"; OFS=" | " } { $1=$1; print }'
email | gmail.com | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd
```

Comment: this is insane! double quotes dont work, single do. lol. many thanks

Comment: I pulled my hair out on that one too. I recall Charles or Ed mentioning the quoting difference, but wouldn't have snapped to it. POSIX requires `"\\"` for each `'\'`, so you need a pair to resolve to `'\'` and another pair so the first isn't taken as an escape.

Comment: Hang on.. gawk script doesnt like single quotes. wth. `#!/usr/bin/gawk -f

BEGIN {
 FS = '[/@:\\\\ ]'
}

{print}`

Comment: In the BEGIN block use double quotes. The 4 slashes from the string will turn into the 2 slashes for the regex, which is what you want. (Single quotes aren't used within awk at all for strings.)

Comment: @jas as i said in gawk neither single nor double quotes work. I have tried 1,2,3,4,5 slashes

Comment: @root there's nothing gawk-specific in your answer.

Comment: @rogerwhite it's not insane at all, single and double quotes have very different semantics/purposes, that's all, you just have to learn how to use each for its intended purpose. Also, don't use a shebang to call awk and also learn what `'` and `"` mean within awk - again they're just different characters with their own semantics. You seem to be assuming that `'` and `"` are interchangeable and mean the same thing across all programming languages - neither of those assumptions is correct which is why you're struggling to use them correctly in both shell and in awk.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `sed` here:

```sh
$ s='email@gmail.com:aaa/bbb\ccc ddd'
$ echo "$s" | sed 's%[/@\: ]% | %g'
email | gmail.com | aaa | bbb | ccc | ddd
```

Tested on `GNU sed`, where `\` isn't needed to be escaped if the character that follows `\` doesn't create a valid escape sequence like `\t`